# Why does Barry bother doing this?

Tags: plot-explanation, barry

At the end of episode 1 of [Barry](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5348176/):

> Barry shoots the sniper and the rest of the people in the car.

Immediately afterwards he:

> strips the gun and throws different parts of it in different directions, but only within a few metres of each other and relatively close to the scene.

These would be easily found and related to each other and to what happened. It does not seem to provide any real protection. Why does he bother?

Comment: That's supposed to be spoiler? From very first episode, without mentioning who exactly he shot? Not to mention this "anti-spoiler" title that, like, only suggests presence of spoiler that isn't here...

Answer (score 2):

Throughout the series, Barry is consistently fairly careless and sloppy with his killings and also excessively trusting of others.

Examples off the top of my head (don't read if you haven't watched the entire series):

> In S03E08 Alfred is able to follow him to a very deserted location where he's burying a body. While Alfred is also a trained Marine, a truly professional contract killer probably wouldn't allow himself to be trailed all the way out to some desert/deserted location by anyone.

> In S03E08 he trusts Gene Cousineau and walks right into a trap.

These mistakes by Barry are so consistent that I don't think these are mistakes by the writers, but intentional and meant to be part of Barry's character (or overall humor of the show).

Comment: It's Albert, not Alfred, but he does make quite a bit of mistakes.